# Error Integrating Mobilefirst with DataPower

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-datapower

I am following this tutorial https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/02/20/datapower-integration/

I have mobilefirst Studio 7.1.0.00-20160528-1648 and datapower 7.1.0.4

I installed the pattern in Datapower ant it works, but when I run the app, when I send the credentials I am getting getting again the login form.

I can see the next error in the messages.log

> [6/13/16 8:45:14:228 CST] 000000f6
>   com.ibm.ws.security.token.internal.TokenManagerImpl          I
>   CWWKS4001E: The security token cannot be validated. This can be for
>   the following reasons
>    1. The security token was generated on another server using different keys.
>    2. The token configuration or the security keys of the token service which created the token has been changed.
>    3. The token service which created the token is no longer available.

I enable the trace com.ibm.ws.security

I see the error

> [6/13/16 8:44:08:801 CST] 00000101 id=46978bb4
>   com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAToken2           1 Caught
>   BadPaddingException while decrypting token, this is only a critical
>   problem if decryption should have worked. 
>                                                                                                                   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly
>   padded

I ran the apps the apps in IOS and Android aand I get the error in the 2 environments

In android also I get this error:

> 06-13 14:44:50.928 2715-3738/com.HybridDataPower
>   W/ResponseProcessCookies: Cookie rejected:
>   "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=forms.mypattern_MFPIntegration_Web_HTTPS_FormLTPA.FormsTarget,domain=192.168.233.139,path=/j_security_check,expiry=null]".
>   Illegal path attribute "/j_security_check". Path of origin:
>   "/DataPower/apps/services/api/HybridDataPower/android/query"  06-13
>   14:44:50.930 2715-2734/com.HybridDataPower
>   W/org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies:
>   Jdk14Logger.log in Jdk14Logger.java:103 :: Cookie rejected:
>   "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=forms.mypattern_MFPIntegration_Web_HTTPS_FormLTPA.FormsTarget,domain=192.168.233.139,path=/j_security_check,expiry=null]".
>   Illegal path attribute "/j_security_check". Path of origin:
>   "/DataPower/apps/services/api/HybridDataPower/android/query"

I am using the default password on the lpa.keys WebAS

I am using a HTTP Handler Service in datapower

I dont know if I need more configuration in DataPower or Mobilefirst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The security token was generated on another server using different keys". This strongly point to a missmatch issue with the LTPA key. Make sure (double-check) that you use the same LTPA key for both Liberty and DataPower.

Login to your DataPower domain. In the search box, search for "AAA Policy".

- In "FormLTPA_Form2LTPA" → "Postprocessing". Re-upload your LTPA key file and re-enter the password. Apply and save.
- In "FormLTPA_Verify" → "Authentication". Re-upload your LTPA key file and re-enter the password. Apply and save.

Of course make sure that your client application points to your DataPower IP and port, and not directly to the MFP server.

A lot of steps could go wrong, so re-read the blog post to make sure you did not miss any. For example I often forget to edit my server.xml to match the user/password for my test.